# TypeError: undefined ins not a function | Simple chat application

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, chat

I'm new to socket.io and I am trying to learn it from a book `Socket.IO Real-Time Web Application Development`.

There is a simple code for chat application that uses Node.js and express. For the server side, there is the `sockets.js` code:

```
var io = require('socket.io');

exports.initialize = function(server) {
    io = io.listen(server);
    io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            message = JSON.parse(message);
            
            if(message.type == "userMessage") {
                socket.get('nickname', function(err, nickname) {
                    message.username = nickname;
                    socket.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                    message.type = "myMessage";
                    socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                });
            }
        });
        
        socket.on("set_name", function(data) {
            socket.set('nickname', data.name, function() {
                socket.emit('name_set', data);
                socket.send(JSON.stringify(
                        {type: 'serverMessage',
                            message: 'Welcome to the chat-room'}
                ));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

For the client side, there is the `chat.js` code:

```
var socket = io.connect('/');

socket.on('name_set', function(data) {
    $('#nameform').hide();
    $('#messages').append('<div class="systemMessage">' + 'Hello ' + data.name + '</div>');
    $('#send').click(function() {
        var data = {
                message: $('#message').val(),
                type: 'userMessage'
        };
        
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        $('#message').val('');
    });
    
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        
        if(data.username) {
            $('#messages').append('<div class="' + data.type + '"><span class="name"'
                    + data.username + ":</span> " + data.message + '</div>');
        }
        else {
            $('#messages').append('<div class="' + data.type + '">' + data.message + '</div>');
        }
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#setname').click(function() {
        socket.emit("set_name", {name: $('#nickname').val()});
    });
});
```

This is the `index.jade` file:

```
extends layout

block content
    section#chatroom
        div#messages
        input#message(type='text', placeholder='Enter your message here')
        input#send(type='button', value='Send')
    section#nameform.modal
        div.backdrop
        div.popup
            div.pophead Please enter a nickname
            div.popbody
                input#nickname(type='text')
                input#setname(type='button', value='Set Name')
```

When I am clicking the `Set Name` button, the error thrown is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/application/routes/sockets.js:20:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.onevent (/path/to/my/application/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:335:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/path/to/my/application/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:295:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/path/to/my/application/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/path/to/my/application/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/path/to/my/application/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (/path/to/my/application/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:175:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.onPacket (/path/to/my/application/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:101:14)
```

It is showing an error on the line

```
socket.set('nickname', data.name, function() {...});
```

in sockets.js.

The only thing different I'm using from the book is the version of socket.io. The book uses version 0.9.10, while I use version 1.4.4. Does this make any difference on this simple code? Also I found out that `socket.set()` is deprecated but gives backward compatibility, so this should work.

Comment: The `set` method is indeed deprecated, have you tried changing `socket.set('nickname', data.name, function() {...})` to `socket.nickname = data.name`?

Comment: @villeaka, but it says there is backward compatibility to them. Moreover, socket.IO is not even well documented on their own website. Hard to swap code from old to new.